# What are the list of Drupal 7 image cropping modules out there?

Tags: media

Currently I use EPSA crop for cropping images as it uses the same image field without making a new one. What are the list of image cropping modules out there that provide a similar functionality? Epsa crop gives me the ability to crop different sized images for different image styles.

Comment: Sorry but questions asking for 'lists' of anything are automatically off-topic on any Stack Exchange site. [Q+A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Image Javascript Crop](http://drupal.org/project/imagecrop) Module.

> This module makes an Imagecache 2 (D6) or Styles (D7) 'javascript crop' toolbox action available for use with several modules.

Answer (score 0):

There is more powerful [Imagefield Crop](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield_crop) module.

> imagefield_crop provides a widget for cropping an image after upload.

It saves a cropped image rather than using some *Imagecache 2 (D6) or Styles (D7)* things on image.